# getting filename error when tried to upload file with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i have a project made with react, node, and mysql. In this project user will be able to login and register, after login(in the homepage) user can input data(images,text) with form. I have 2 form page, the first page is data + image, and the second page is input type checkbox. But dont worry about the second page because the problem is in the first page.

The problem is upload file/image, i kept getting error about filename. `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename').` and the result in the database is `localhost:3001/images/undefined`. But the other data is inputted fine, only the image is undefined. Btw i use context

How do you fix this.

**FormDataContext**

```
import React from 'react';
import {createContext, useState} from "react"
export const FormData = createContext();
export default function FormDataProvider({children}) {
    const [formData , setFormData] = useState({
        cName : "",
        Address : "",
        phoneNumber : 0,
        presidentName : "",
        managerEmail : "",
        managerPhone : 0,
        picEmail : "",
        picPhone : 0,
        date: "",
        mainBusiness : "",
        employeeNumber : "",
        numberOfCustomer : "",
        myFile : "",
      });
  return (
    <FormData.Provider value={{ formData, setFormData }}>
     {children}
    </FormData.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Form.js**

```
const Form = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  

    const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser);
    const { loginStatus, setLoginStatus } = useContext(LoginStatus);
    const { formData , setFormData} = useContext(FormData);


  return (
    <form method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' action='http://localhost:3001/registration'>

    <div className='sign-up-container'>
      <input type='email' value={emailLog} name='email' onChange={(e) => {
        setEmailLog(e.target.value) }} />
      <input type='text' placeholder='Company Name' name="CompanyName" value={formData.cName}  onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, cName: event.target.value })}/>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Address' name="Address" value={formData.Address} onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, Address: event.target.value })}  />
      <input type='tel' placeholder='Phone Number' name="Phone" value={formData.phoneNumber} onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, phoneNumber: event.target.value })}  />
      <input type='text' placeholder='President Director Name' name="PresidentName" value={formData.presidentName} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, presidentName: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='email' placeholder='Manager Email' name="ManagerEmail" value={formData.managerEmail} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, managerEmail: event.target.value})}  />
      <input type='tel'  placeholder='Manager Phone' name="ManagerPhone" value={formData.managerPhone} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, managerPhone: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='email'  placeholder='PIC Email' name="PICEmail" value={formData.picEmail} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, picEmail: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='tel'  placeholder='PIC Phone' name="PICPhone" value={formData.picPhone} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, picPhone: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='date'  placeholder='Date' name="EstablishedDate" value={formData.date} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, date: event.target.value})} />
        <select className='selectBox' name='ChoiceBusiness'  onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({...formData, mainBusiness: event.target.value})} >
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Main Business...</option>
                  <option value="Software License">Software License</option>
                  <option value="IT Services & Consulting">IT Services & Consulting</option>
                  <option value="IT Outsourcing">IT Outsourcing</option>
                  <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                  <option value="General Trading">General Trading</option>
                  <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
        <select className='selectBox' name='EmployeeNumber'  onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({...formData, employeeNumber: event.target.value})} >
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Employee Number...</option>
                <option value="1-50">1-50</option>
                <option value="51-100">51-100</option>
                <option value="101-250">101-250</option>
                <option value="251-500">251-500</option>
                <option value="500+">500+</option>
        </select>
      <input type="number"  placeholder='Number of Customer' name="NumberOfCustomer" value={formData.numberOfCustomer} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, numberOfCustomer: event.target.value})} />
      <input type="file" name='pdfFiles' onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, myFile : event.target.value})}  />
    </div>
    </form>
  )
}


export default Form
```

**FormDefault.js**

```
const FormDefault = () => {

  const [page, setPage ] = useState(0);

  const FormTitles = ["Supplier formData.Data", "Document Required"];

  const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser);
  const { formData , setFormData} = useContext(FormData);

  const [file, setFile] = useState();

  const sendForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/registration" , {
        email : emailLog,
        CompanyName : formData.cName,
        Address : formData.Address,
        Phone : formData.phoneNumber,
        PresidentName : formData.presidentName,
        ManagerEmail : formData.managerEmail,
        ManagerPhone : formData.managerPhone,
        PICEmail : formData.picEmail,
        PICPhone : formData.picPhone,
        EstablishedDate : formData.date,
        ChoiceBusiness : formData.mainBusiness,
        EmployeeNumber : formData.employeeNumber,
        NumberOfCustomer : formData.numberOfCustomer,
        imgsrc : formData.myFile
    }).then((response)=> {
      console.log(response) 
    })
  }
  
  const PageDisplay = () => {
    if ( page == 0 ){
        return <Form  formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
    } else if ( page == 1) {
        return <FormCheckbox />
    } 
  };

  return (
    <div className='form'>
        <div className='progressbar'>
            <div style={{width : page == 0 ? "50%" : "100%"}}></div>
        </div>
    

        <div className='form container'>
            <div className='header'>
                <h1>{FormTitles[page]}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className='body'>{PageDisplay()}</div>
            <div className='footer'>
                <button 
                disabled={ page == 0}
                onClick={() => {
                    setPage((currPage) => currPage -1 )
                }}>Prev</button>
                <button type='submit' onClick={sendForm}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
               
      
                <button 
                disabled={page == FormTitles.length - 1}
                onClick={() => {
                        setPage((currPage) => currPage + 1 )
                    
                }}>Next
                </button>
    </div>

  )
}

export default FormDefault
```

**index.js(backend)**

```
const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "work"
});

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'Images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() +  path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
    session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: "subscribe",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
    },
})
);

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post("/registration", upload.single('pdfFiles'), (req, res) => {
    const Email = req.body.email;
    const CompanyName = req.body.CompanyName;
    const Address = req.body.Address;
    const PhoneNumber = req.body.Phone;
    const PresidentName = req.body.PresidentName;
    const ManagerEmail = req.body.ManagerEmail;
    const ManagerPhone = req.body.ManagerPhone;
    const PICEmail = req.body.PICEmail;
    const PICPhone = req.body.PICPhone;
    const EstablishedDate = req.body.EstablishedDate;
    const MainBusiness = req.body.ChoiceBusiness;
    const EmployeeNumber = req.body.EmployeeNumber;
    const NumberCustomer = req.body.NumberOfCustomer;
    const SK  = req.body.SK

    const imgsrc = `localhost:3001/images/${req.file.filename}`
   
    q = "INSERT INTO mahalkita(Email, CompanyName, Address, PhoneNumber, PresidentName, AccountManagerEmail, AccountManagerPhone, PICEmail, PICPhone, EstablishedDate, MainBusiness, EmployeeNumber, NumberOfCustomer, Attachments, SKMenhum) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    db.query(q, [Email, CompanyName, Address, PhoneNumber, PresidentName, ManagerEmail, ManagerPhone, PICEmail, PICPhone, EstablishedDate, MainBusiness, EmployeeNumber, NumberCustomer, imgsrc, SK], (err, result) => {
       console.log(err)
       console.log(result)
        res.send("uploaded")
    })
})


app.get("/getUserRegistration", (req, res) => {
    const Test = req.body.email;
    
    const sqlSelect= `SELECT * from mahalkita INNER JOIN user ON mahalkita.email = user.email WHERE user.email  = "${req.session.email[0].email}" ORDER BY mahalkita.id DESC LIMIT 1`
    db.query(sqlSelect, Test, (err, result)=>{
        res.send(result)
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont think that you can send a file with JSON. Instead you need to send it as formdata-encoded

Comment: const imgsrc = `localhost:3001/images/${req.files.filename}`. do you know how to make this an array. If i tried to upload multiple file it return in the database as localhost:3001/images/undefined